# I have flipped faces on my normal map, but not on my HP or LP model. What's happening? (Version 2.9.3)

Tags: texturing, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

So, i've been modeling a Nintendo Switch for portfolio. I'm pretty new to baking.

HighPoly face orientation:
[image]

LowPoly face orientation:[image]

Normal map on SRGB looks good:
[image]

But when i change to Non-Color...
[image]

Any idea of what can be causing this issue?

Comment: The normal map will bake to whatever format you have specified in the image texture at the time of bake.  If it was set to sRGB at time of bake, it is not in a non-color color space (oxymoron lol.)  Normal map both baked and used as sRGB *should* be okay but in my experience isn't (don't know why.)  Recommend setting to non-color, rebaking, then continuing to use as non-color.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you very much for the help!

It's my first time baking and i didn't know that i had to set it to non-color before baking. 

It's perfect now!